# How to upload HTML web pages on Apache2 web server

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, apache2, html

I have created some HTML files which I want to upload to the web. I am currently running the Apache2 server with my IP address. This is what I see in the browser when I enter my IP address:

[image: Screenshot of what I see]

I am able to access my HTML files using the web browser, but I want to be able to upload them to the web with ordinary web addresses so users can see them. I hope someone can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Your apache isn't setup well, and what do you mean by "I am able to access my HTML"?

Comment: I am able to open my HTML files using the web browser, by opening the files in the browser from my file manager. How would you suggest I set up the apache?

Answer (score 0):

When you type in your **IP address** or **localhost** or **127.0.0.1** in a URL of any web browser, it always searches for an **index.php** or an **index.html** to open. If it doesn't exist, it just shows files on that folder.

> What you see here is your screenshot is the **index.html** file located in the directory **/var/www/html/**

I believe you're hosting a website on your local system. Since you're running **Apache2** as your **Web Server**. All your HTML files are needed to be placed within the directory **/var/www/html/**.

All you need to do the following:

- Delete or rename that **index.html** in that directory. (You'll probably have to do it in sudo mode through terminal, else just give yourself access to read/write/execute all files within the html directory)
- Now place your desired HTML file which is to be your "Homepage" and make sure it is named as **index.html** or **index.php**
- That's it, you're good to go !

*Now enter your IP address in your Browser URL, and you can see your HTML file.*

> A few additional tips:
>
> - Make sure your Apache2 is running before you can view anything on your browser. If youre not sure, just type this command in the Terminal: **sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart**
> - Make sure you, (the user) has read/write/execute privileges on all files and folders in the **/var/www/html** folder.

Comment: Thanks for that. How do I delete the index.html file using the Terminal? I tried to delete it normally and the option was greyed out.

Comment: Follow these steps:
1-Open your directory location /var/www/html
2-Right click in the directory, and click on "Open In Terminal"
3-Type in the command:
  sudo chmod 777 *


(You now can delete and do anything you like within that folder)
4-Now add your new index.html or index.php inside

Comment: Thanks. I was able to remove it simply using sudo rm.

Comment: That's an easy way out. You'll run into issues later as you wont be able to add new files, unless you give yourself complete permissions to that folder and all other subfolders. I suggest you change the permissions to that folder, to have a smoother time testing your Website.